# Confusion over using abstract class in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question since I'm new in programming Im really confused about how to implement a best practice solution for the following problem, Its a game logic,here are the possible ways of making points

```
EnemyA 400,
EnemyB 500,
EnemyC 700,
Coin   200,
FireBall 300
```

means hitting `Coin` gives you 200 points and shooting `FireBall` gives you 300 &...

if you reach 1000 points you will get an extra life, the logic simple but implementing the best practice is not(at least to me)should I use `abstract class` or `Dictionary`?

So far, I used a `Dictionary`, I read a given file (txt) file which is written (EnemyA,EnemyB,Coin,Coin,Coin,Coin) then I calculate the points:

```cs
public int pointCal(IEnumerable<string> enemyType)
{
    var possiblePoints = new Dictionary< EnemisEntity,int>()
    {
        {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="EnemyA"},400 },
        {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="EnemyB" },500 },
        {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="EnemyC"},700 },
        {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="Fireball"},300 },
        {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="Coin"},200 },
    };
    int z=0;
    List<int> myPoints=new List<int> ();         
    foreach (var item in enemyType)
    {
        z = possiblePoints.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key.enemyType.Equals(item)).Value;
                myPoints.Add(z);
    }
    int finalPonts= g.Sum(s=>Convert.ToInt32(s));
    return finalPonts;
}


  Enemy entity class:

     public  class EnemisEntity
    {
       public string enemyType { get; set; }
       
     }
```

Comment: Class hierarchies should not be used to implement _game rules_. Class hierarchives represent an "**is**" relationship - and an "enemy" and a "coin" do not share any "is" relationship beyond trivial "is game-entity"-style relationships which is bunk.

Comment: In your case this is homework style material. For learning purpose any way works. If i were you i would go the route to have as much flexibility as i can and try different things. Perhaps 2 files one you read the possible items and their value and the second file contains the list of value to evaluate the score. Also watchout for asking for the "best way" of of doing something. This highly tend to create opinionated answers which are not allowed on this site.

Comment: @Dai can you explain more?what i did is ok?

Comment: The use of classes and objects in this example is quite strange. You construct the enemies just to give points. After that, they are gone again. One might ask how the game works when the enemies live only inside the points calculation method.

Comment: @ThomasWeller separate class for all enemies?

Comment: No. One class but many objects

Comment: "what i did is ok?" Regarding on how to ask in stack overflow, you did fine, but you should try to post more concrete answers. Regarding the code, you did good, your objects have the same structure (name/type and points) so there is no need to create several classes

Comment: That's not a good usage of a dictionary.  Since you just iterate through it to find a match using `FirstOrDefault` you might as well construct a list.  You might want to use `TryGetValue` instead, but then it would make more sense to use the `string` value as the key instead of the `EnemisEntity`.

Comment: Please show us the class definition of `EnemisEntity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Are the enemies different types of objects (with different properties and such)?

Then it might make sense to create an abstract class and child classes.

```
public abstract class Shootable {
    public int points;
}

public class EnemyA: Shootable {
}

public class EnemyB: Shootable {
}

public class Coin: Shootable {
}

// etc
```

If all your items are just shootable with one description, then

```
public class Shootable {
    public int points { get; set; }
    public string enemyType { get; set; }
    public Shootable(int points, string enemyType ){
        this.points = points;
        this.enemyType = enemyType;
    }
}

// then create like
var coin = new Shootable(500, "coin");
```

If all enemies can be modeled in the same class, then you only need shootable class

Then get the points:

```
IEnumerble<Shootable> shootableItems = GetShootableFromFile();
var score = shootableItems.Sum(s => s.Points);
```

You `GetShootableFromFile` should create one object per file row. So it is a viable situation to create the same objects twice:

```
// This is a mock to indicate multiple instances of the same class.
public IEnumerble<Shootable> GetShootableFromFile() {
    List<Shootable> shootable = new List<Shootable>();
    shootable.Add(new Shootable(500,"coin"));
    shootable.Add(new Shootable(500,"coin"));
    shootable.Add(new Shootable(500,"coin"));
    shootable.Add(new Shootable(300,"enemyA"));
    shootable.Add(new Shootable(300,"enemyB"));
    // etc
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. A coin class is useless when you can construct a coin by instantiating a Shootable.

Comment: Since the current implementation relies on strings to define the targets it seems logical to me to have one class that contains all the information needed (like your 2nd option).

Comment: Indeed! Looks like it's the way to go. In case though if EnemyA is a kind of `AnimalEnemy` and EnemyB is of type `HumanEnemy` with different member, it would make sense to have a base class.

Comment: regarding the second option after i add all these,for looking up I should use for loop or dictionary?which is the best way?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Use linq on the `IEnumerable<Shootable>` collection.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this is a question of design. When the only difference between enemies is just the value of points as well as their name it is not a good idea to define a class hierarchy. The only thing different between a `EnemyA` and a `EnemyB` class would be just the values contained within each class. So you can use a single common class to hold information for each enemy and process the points.

Below is the simplest working prototype that I could code that implements this design. It relies on two classes. The `EnemyEntity` class to hold the type of enemy and its points, and a `Game` class that contains the logic behind scoring and keeping a record of all possible enemies.

```
public class EnemyEntity
{
    public EnemyEntity(string type, int points)
    {
        Type=type;
        Points=points;
    }

    public string Type { get; }
    public int Points { get; }
}

public class Game
{
    public Game(params (string type, int points)[] values)
    {
        this.Enemies = new List<EnemyEntity>();
        foreach (var (type, points) in values)
        {
            Enemies.Add(new EnemyEntity(type, points));
        }
    }

    public List<EnemyEntity> Enemies { get; }

    public int CalculatePoints(IEnumerable<string> targets)
    {
        int points = 0;
        foreach (var item in targets)
        {
            var target = Enemies.FirstOrDefault((enemy) => enemy.Type.Equals(item));
            if (target!=null)
            {
                points+= target.Points;
            }
        }
        return points;
    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var game = new Game(
            ("EnemyA", 400),
            ("EnemyB", 500),
            ("EnemyC", 700),
            ("Coin", 200),
            ("FireBall", 300));

        var input = "EnemyA,EnemyB,Coin,Coin,Coin,Coin";
        var targets = input.Split(',');
        var points = game.CalculatePoints(targets);

        Console.WriteLine(points);
        // 1700
    }
}
```

---

NOTES:

The simplest approach is to use a `List<EnemyEntity>` and do the lookup with `.FirstOrDefault()`. I could use a `Dictionary<string,EnemyEntity>` which would simplify the lookup process. Here is how the `Game` class would change using a dictionary.

```
public class Game
{
    public Game(params (string type, int points)[] values)
    {
        this.Enemies = new Dictionary<string, EnemyEntity>();
        foreach (var (type, points) in values)
        {
            Enemies[type] = new EnemyEntity(type, points);
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, EnemyEntity> Enemies { get; }

    public int CalculatePoints(IEnumerable<string> targets)
    {
        int points = 0;
        foreach (var item in targets)
        {
            var target = Enemies[item];
            if (target!=null)
            {
                points+= target.Points;
            }
        }
        return points;
    }

}
```

Comment: mai ask why the name of the method is as same as the class name?Game(params (string type, int points)[] values)and why you did not write Game(string Type,int point)what are params and []values?

Comment: That is the constructor of a class. It is how you specify to initialize `Game` with values. You call the constructor as you see in the main program as `var game = new Game(...);`